# Deleting a maven project from Mercurial in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mercurial

My current project consists of a single Mercurial repository containing multiple Maven projects. In Eclipse, most of the Mercurial operations are handled smoothly (or I've gotten used to the foibles), but I've never found a nice, smooth way to remove a Maven project. It always seems to involve having to go into the file system and manually handling the removal. Just deleting the project from the Eclipse workspace + filesystem does not seem to work.

Is there a best practice that makes deleting Maven projects from Mercurial-managed workspaces smooth? Or is that just a fact-of-life?

Comment: I think you can remove project from file system also. When you delete proejct from eclipse, you will see one confirmation dialog where there is one check box ¨Delete project contents on disk (can not be undone)¨?
If you click on it then it will remove it from file system also.

Comment: When that directory is under Mercurial-control, that doesn't happen; or at least, Mercurial doesn't seem to notice.